# Youtube video ends fade out

Tags: jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to make my youtube video api frame fade out after playing, but can't get it to work. It worked a while ago, but I must have done something to the script to mess it up.

I have tried `document.getElementById("video").style.display = "none";` aswell, and that doesn't work. I really want to make it fade out.

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '480',
        width: '853',
        videoId: '7u-liW-xRE4',
        playerVars: { 
         'autoplay': 1,
         'showinfo': 0,
         'controls': 0, 
         'rel' : 0

  }
    });

}



function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

var done = false;

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
    if(event.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {          
        stopVideo();
    }
}

function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
    document.getElementById("video").fadeOut();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the event that is send by the YT Api when the video has ended. Now you're giving the command to end the video. That are two different things. Try this:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {

         console.log('awesome video playing');      

    }
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {

        jQuery('your element').fadeTo('fast', 0).hide();

    }   
}
```

And I'd advise you not to mix javascript and jquery styling in your code as this can be confusing.

Comment: So I remove everything below onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() and place what you said? What do I put in 'awesome video playing'?

Comment: Eh, no.

onPlayerReady(event) does not interfere with what I said. That's your autoplay function.

What you want is something unrelated to that.
You can use the onPLayerStateChange(event) seperately from the onPLayerReady function.

but what's really easy is to just copypasta the functioning code at https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=nl and then just change it where you need.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I keep the code I already have and palce your thing at the bottom? Do i need the PLAYING state?

Comment: Obviously the PLAYING state is only there for reference. If you want to execute something after the video ended use ENDED. If you want something to execute when paused use PAUSED.
So you can copy my code in your code after what you already have or you can adapt the code from the google developers page.
It's really insightfull, you should read it.

Comment: Please value answers if they're helpfull.